# The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values ', *', but only one is allowed in spring boot stomp configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, stomp

I was configuration stomp in spring boot, I was set setAllowedOrigins but when connect to Sockjs by chrome has errors, how do i resolve this problem?

```
@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    
    registry
    .addEndpoint("/agent")
    .setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.stream(domainAllowed.split(",")).toArray(String[]::new))
    //.setAllowedOrigins("*")
    .withSockJS();
    
    logger.info("out register");
}

@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    
    logger.info("thong tin domain allowed: "+ domainAllowed);
    
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.stream(domainAllowed.split(",")).map(String::trim).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    configuration.setMaxAge(-1L);
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://cli.ovp.vn/agent/info?t=1632386394912' from origin '' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'https://domain.work, *', but only one is allowed.

stomp.min.js:8 Whoops! Lost connection to

Comment: It seems `domainAllowed` has same values.
Could you share what log is displayed after execution : logger.info("thong tin domain allowed: "+ domainAllowed); Could you remove duplicate values (if it's somehting hard coded)? or just try `distinct` operation in your Stream

Comment: The setAllowedOrigns property of the registry method is already capable of accepting one or multiple origins. Just separate each origin with a comma, e.g. ("origin 1","origin 2").